# Extracting data frames from a list based on column names in r

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, extract

I am looking at extracting df's from within a list of multiple df's into separate data frames based on a condition (if the column names of a df within the list contains the name I am looking for).

For illustration purposes I have created an example which resembles the situation I am in.

I have list with multiple data frames and the dput of that list is given below:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(list(lvef = c(0.965686195194885, 
0.0806777632648268, -0.531729196500083, -0.511913109608259, -0.413670941196816, 
-0.0501899795864357, -0.337583918771946, 1.16086745780346, -0.478358865835724, 
-1.95009138673888), hbc = c(-0.389950511350405, -0.904388183933348, 
0.811821977223064, -0.868381700124344, -0.637307418402866, -1.04703715824204, 
-0.394340445217658, -0.194653869597247, 0.00822402232044511, 
-0.145032587618231), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NA", class = "factor")), .Names = c("lvef", 
"hbc", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), 
V2 = structure(list(ersta = c(-0.254360310986174, 0.3859806928747, 
-0.135741797055127, 1.03929145413636, -0.484219739337178, 
0.255476285148917, 1.0479422937128, 0.146613094683722, -0.914377222535014, 
1.75052418161618, -0.275059500684816, 2.34861397588234, 0.00183723766664941, 
0.97612891408903, 0.278868537504227, 0.456979477254684, 1.46323739326792, 
0.664511602217853, 0.870420202897545, 1.38228375734407), 
pgrsta = c(-1.49129812271989, 0.820330747101906, -0.0469488167129374, 
0.471549380446308, -1.71312120132398, 0.0578140025416816, 
1.67016363826724, 0.226180835709491, -2.00294530465909, 
-0.0464857361954717, 0.306942902768782, -0.785096914460742, 
0.283822632249141, -0.260774679911329, -1.2865970194309, 
0.307972619170242, 0.223715024597144, -1.01642533651475, 
-0.12229427204957, 0.223326519096996), id = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("-0.10863576856322", 
"-0.317324527228699", "-0.422764348315332", "0.285132258310185", 
"1.23305496219042", "1.39326602279981", "NA"))), .Names = c("ersta", 
"pgrsta", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame"), 
V3 = structure(list(hormrec = 1:15, event = structure(c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"NA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("hormrec", "event"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame"), V4 = structure(list(asat = c(-0.321423784000631, 
0.181345361079582, 0.389158724418319, -1.15251833725336, 
-0.351981383678293, -0.506888212379408, 0.870705917350059, 
-0.626883041051641, -0.321843006223371, -0.674564527029912, 
-0.609383943267379, -0.181661119817784, -1.63676077872658
), lab = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("btest", "NA", "rtest"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("asat", 
"lab"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"))
```

I am trying to extract data frames from the list based on the condition that if a data frame within the list contains the column name/s required then that data frame from the list should go into a separate data frame. So far, I have been able to extract the data frames into a list using the following code:

```
# function to extract required df's
        trial <- function(x) 
    {  
      reqname <- c("hbc","ersta") # column names to check for
      data <- x

      lapply(seq(data), function(i){ # loop through all the data frames in the list
        y <- data.frame(data[[i]]) # extract df in y
        names <- names(y) # extract names of df
        for(a in 1:length(reqname)) # loop through the length of reqname
        {
        if(reqname[a]%in%names) # check if column name/s present in current df
            {
              z <- y # extract df into another df
                return(z) # return df
            }
        }
      }
          )
    }
```

The above function returns a list of matching df's along with nulls where there was not a match. I am looking for a modification so that the selected data frame comes out separately. If there are two df's matching the requirement then the output should be two separate data frames.

I will appreciate all and any help in finding a solution.

Comment: What is your expected output?  If you want to remove the NULL elements,  `lst1 <- Filter(length, trial(lst))`  If you need some data.frame objects in the global environment, `list2env(setNames(lst1, paste0('dat' seq_along(lst1))), envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: My expected output will be multiple data frames but not in a list. Currently the function returns a list with NULL elements. e.g., using the example list and function in the post - I should have two seperate data frames as a result. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just try the `list2env`.  It will be two dataframe objects.

Comment: This list2env statement should be placed within the IF block? can you ellaborate what is "dat"? should the statement be list2env(setName(z,paste0("dat",seqalong(z))), envir=.GlobalEnv)?

Comment: By using `paste0('dat', ...)`, we name the list elements as 'dat1' and 'dat2'.  after the `list2env`, you can type `dat1` and get the first data.frame object

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use the `lapply()` plus a custom function to identify wanted outputs. For instance, if k is your list,

```
trial <- function(x) 
    {
        reqnames <- c("hbc","ersta")
        k <- lapply(k, function(x)  any(names(x) %in% reqnames))
        k <- which(k==1)
        x[k]
    }
```

This outputs a list with only the dataframes containing at least one of the names in reqnames.

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the `NULL` elements with `Filter`

```
 lst1 <- Filter(length, trial(lst))
```

If we need multiple data.frame objects in the global environment, use `list2env` after renaming the `list` elements with the object names

```
 names(lst1) <- paste0('dat' seq_along(lst1))
 list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```